# Создание акта в word C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

Доброго времени суток. Нужно создать акт в word на основе данных, имеющихся на winforms.
Подскажите, как лучше это сделать или с чего вообще начать? 
На листе будет отформатированный текст и таблица, число строк в которой каждый раз будет разным, но не более 10.
Примерный внешний вид акта можно увидеть на фото ниже. Места, где замазано, как раз надо будет заменить на свои. Ну и, как писал выше, добавить строки в таблицу. В изначальном шаблоне есть только шапка таблицы, без строк.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Взять библиотеку для экспорта в docx, например https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx, создать шаблон вашего документа и по ходу выполнения программы заменять данные в шаблоне реальными

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй стандартное расширение Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word и подготовь шаблон с данного документа с закладками в требуемых местах. Краткий код работы с документом:

```
Word._Document document;
Word._Application application=new Word.Application();
object missingObj = Missing.Value;
object templatePathObj = documentpath;

//открытие файла
try
{
    document = application.Documents.Add(ref templatePathObj,
            ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
}
catch
{
    document.Close(ref falseobj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
    application.Quit(ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
    document = null;
    application = null;
}

//заполнение закладок
object bookmarkObj = "закладка";
Word.Range bookmarkRange = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj).Range;
bookmarkRange.Text = "";

//работа с таблицей
// Выбрать уже существующую таблицу внутри документа
// можно по ее порядковому номеру (начиная с 1 и начала документа)
Word.Table _table = _document.Tables[tableNumber];
_table.Rows.Add(ref _missingObj);
Word.Range _currentRange = _table.Cell(rowIndex, columnIndex).Range;
_currentRange.Text="";

//Вывод на печать
document.PrintOut(ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj,
        ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj,
        ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj,
        ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj,
        ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);

document.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
application.Quit();
```

Подробно об этом расширении есть [тут](http://nullpro.info/2012/ms-word-iz-vstavlyaem-tekst-i-formatiruem/) и [тут](http://nullpro.info/2012/rabotaem-s-ms-word-iz-c-chast-3-rabota-s-tablicami/).

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в свой ответ хотя бы небольшой пример кода. Ссылки могут "умереть" и ваш ответ потеряет свою ценность.

Comment: если мне нужно вставить одну  ту же информацию в двух разных местах, то надо создавать две закладки? Добавив две закладки с одним именем, первая исчезает  И есть ли способ более кратко указать закладки и их значения, чем таким вот образом: object bookmarkObj = "z1";
            object bookmarkObj1 = "z2";
            Word.Range bookmarkRange = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj).Range;
            Word.Range bookmarkRange1 = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj1).Range;
            bookmarkRange.Text = textBox1.Text;
            bookmarkRange1.Text = "1231243543234";

Comment: _если мне нужно вставить одну ту же информацию в двух разных местах, то надо создавать две закладки?_ Именно. Закладки в шаблоне должны быть с разными именами чтобы иметь понятие какая к чему относится. Поочередно заполняй закладки и это будет читабельно.

Comment: Для исключения дублирования можешь создать метод с входящими значениями имя закладки и текст. И использовать его для сокращения кода

Comment: А как в таблице можно сделать автоматический перенос слов? У меня сейчас переносятся буквы и это не очень красиво. [скрин](http://ibb.co/k09KDH). table.Rows.WrapAroundText = 1; Пытался таким вот кодом установить автоперенос, но не работает. И не уверен, что это вообще оно.

Comment: У тебя на скрине цельно без пробелов записаны заправки, он его разделять не будет. Добавь пробелы